# Funcion recibe tabla de datos

Tags: postgresql, funciones, function

Les comento, yo tengo una función

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_funcion(x numeric) 
RETURNS TABLE(codigo character varying) AS 'consulta'

LANGUAGE
    sql;
```

La cual al ingresar una id ( X ) me trae una lista de codigos de compras de ese cliente..eso funciona perfecto, lo que yo queria saber es si existia alguna posibilidad para que esa lista de codigos que me devuelve las pueda poner como dato de entrada a otra funcion, por ejemplo

```
funcion1 (x numeric)

funcion2 (todos los codigos que me trajo la funcion1)
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estoy dando una respuesta parcial ya que no has provisto de suficiente información para aclarar totalmente la pregunta.

Puedes crear la segunda función que tenga como parámetro único un arreglo y en la primera función lo que harías es pasarle los datos en esa forma.

No puedo especificar el código para su realización porque no has mencionado de qué manera recibes los códigos de compras del cliente (a través de un ciclo o con variables).